# Getting an AMI BIOS error beep code although the PC seems to work perfectly fine

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, bios, physical-damage

I have a problem with a brand new [Spectra PowerTwin desktop PC](https://www.spectra.de/files/produkte/KA008667/web/Manual-Spectra_PowerTwin-P_Core-i_Serie_Rev1.6.pdf).

Sometimes when booting, I get a 5x short-beep error code¹, but I don't know why as the PC seems to be working perfectly fine.

The only thing I changed was to install a [PCI CAN card](//www.peak-system.com/PCAN-PCI.207.0.html) in the system, which also works fine. (I checked with `dmesg`.)

---

¹ *"Five short beeps means there has been a processor error. A damaged expansion card, the CPU, or the motherboard could be prompting this AMI beep code."*